# DRF @property field serializer Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field X on serializer Y

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework for serialize and update a @property field, but i'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `template` on serializer `PublicationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Publication` instance.
Original exception text was: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'template'.
```

i have the following models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    @property
    def template(self):
        return self.apps.first().template

class App(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='apps')
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, blank=True, null=True)

class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Public name'), max_length=255, db_column='nome')
```

and the following serializer:

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    template = TemplateSerializer(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Publication
        fields = ('template',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        template_data = validated_data.pop('template', None)
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        if template_data:
            instance.apps.all().update(template__id=template_data['id'])
        return instance
```

This error happens when i use GET method to view and my Publication.apps is empty, and when i try to use POST method, i receive an empty `OrderedDict()` object.

This looks like when my field is null the DRF can't discover field type, and when my i try to POST the serializer isn't working as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like publication you are trying to use don't have related apps. That's why `self.apps.first()` return `None` and `self.apps.first().template` raise exception. Try to change property to this:

```
@property
def template(self):
    return getattr(self.apps.first(), 'template', None)
```